# Google Nearby notification not shows when i near to beacone

Tags: android, bluetooth, eddystone, google-nearby, google-beacon-platform

I was just trying to create google near by notification for my beacons but Notification still visible through the nearby app. But it's not shows automatically when I reach near to beacon. I create a beacon app in google developer console and register the beacon and create the notification for that.
All of them are ok. but notification not shows in automatically.When i testing by my Samsung edge and nexus5 android phone. I have double checked for location and bluetooth services are on.
[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand this correctly, you can see the notification when you open Nearby, but not in the notification drawer.

There are several reasons a notification may not appear.

- A notification won't show if the attachment is not well received by
  users. Tips for creating a great attachment can be found above.
- An attachment in    Debug mode will only show on debug mode devices.
- If the notification has been dismissed on a device recently, that
  device may not show another notification a period of time. The
  backoff policy is also reset if the user opens the Nearby section of
  Google Settings.

So my advice would be check if the attachment is in debug mode. If not, try to reset the the backoff policy from the Nearby section.
Also, sometimes the notifications aren't 'instant'. Unlock your screen and give it some time. These are low priority notifications.

Hope this helps! Good luck :)